# Send a request directly to a server

Tags: node.js

I've been hunting for a solution for this for quite a while and haven't found anything. The [docs](https://iojs.org/api/http.html) don't have any examples of such a thing, so maybe it just isn't possible. Anyhow, here's the question:

If I create an http server like this:

```
this.server = http.createServer(...);
return this.server;
```

...is it possible, later, to somehow pipe data directly to/from the `this.server` object, which I still have a reference to, rather than figuring out what port or socket it's listening on and sending there?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question [elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/P42GaF0QeWY) and got some useful info from Ryan Graham, so I'll "answer" my own question here for posterity. It should be possible to have your server listen on an ephemeral port by doing this:

```
server.listen(0)
```

...and then connect to it using:

```
var addr = server.address()
http.request(addr.port, addr.address, ...)
```

As I understand, `listen(0)` will listen on a random port, meaning that node will select from some standard range of ephemeral ports intended for this exactly this sort of thing.